# Generating multilevel associative array using php loop

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to generate array for json output from a nested php loop, any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Here is the current code am I using

```
$v_id=0;
$x=0;
$item[] = array();
foreach ($abc as $vm) {
    foreach ($vm->activity as $record) {

        $item['instruction']              = $record->step;
        $item['id']              = $x;
        $id++;

    } 
    $v_id++;
}
```

However each loop of the main loop statement is overrating the previous entries

This is the desired output

```
steps": [
        {
            "v_id": 0,
            "instruction_steps": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "instruction": "<p>Select something </p>",
                  
                   
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "instruction": "<p>Do something</p>",
                   
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: You need to use array_push() inside the loop

Comment: Can you be more specific

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: syntax for array_push() is `$item[] = ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `array_push()`

```
$v_id=0;

$steps = array();

foreach ($abc as $vm) {
   $item = array();
   $item["v_id"] = $v_id;

   $instruction_steps = array();
   $x=0; // This will reset for each

    foreach ($vm->activity as $record) {
      $row = array();
      $row['id'] = $x;
      $row["instruction"] = $record->step;
      array_push($instruction_steps, $row); // push to i-steps

      $x++;

    }
    $item["instruction_steps"] = $instruction_steps;
    array_push($steps, $item); // push to steps

    $v_id++;
}

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;
$response["steps"] = $steps;
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: For some reason the output is not including the nested loop data. See below
 
{"success":true,"steps":[{"v_id":0},{"v_id":1},{"v_id":2},{"v_id":3},{"v_id":4},{"v_id":5},{"v_id":6}]}

Comment: @jmadd yes Edited the answer. Just added `$item["instruction_steps"] = $instruction_steps;` Pelase check it

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple method:

```
$sub_array = [
        [
            ["id"=>"0","instruction"=>"Follow"],["id"=>"1","instruction"=>"Follow 1"]
        ],
        [
            ["id"=>"0","instruction"=>"Follow1"],["id"=>"1","instruction"=>"Follow 1"]
        ]
    ];

$First_step_array = array();

foreach($sub_array as $index => $s_a )
{
    array_push(
           $First_step_array, 
               array(
                   'v_id' => $index,
               'instruction_steps'=>$s_a
               )
          );
}


print_r(json_decode(json_encode($First_step_array)));
```

Output will be:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                             [v_id] => 0 
                             [instruction_steps] => Array ( 

                                         [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 0 [instruction] => Follow )
                                         [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [instruction] => Follow 1 ) 
                                                           
                                                           ) 
  ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                            [v_id] => 1 
                            [instruction_steps] => Array (

                                         [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 0 [instruction] => Follow1 )
                                         [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [instruction] => Follow 1 )
                                                  
                                                          ) 
   )

 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not building a multi-dimensional array.  As you can see, `$item['instruction']` is being overwritten each time because you're not specifying a secondary dimension.  Each iteration of the inner loop needs to have the `$record->step` and `$x` added to *another* array, then that array gets added to `$item[]`

```php
$items[] = array();// pluralized
$v_id=0;
foreach ($abc as $vm) {
    $x=0;
    foreach ($vm->activity as $record) {
        $item = [// $item is now a sub-array
            'instruction'=>$record->step,
            'id'=>$x
        ];
        $items[] = $item; // Add the sub-array to the main array, creating your second dimension
        $x++;// your code had $id++
    } 
    $v_id++;
}
```

That will make `$items` have a structure like:

```
[
  [
    "id":0,
    "instruction"=>"..."
  ],
  [
    "id"=>1,
    "instruction"=>"..."
  ]
]
```

Also, if `$vm` and `$record` are iterable as arrays, they might already have indexes you can use as ids, since it seems the ids are just arbitrary anyway:

```
$items[] = array();// pluralized
foreach ($abc as $vid => $vm) {
    foreach ($vm->activity as $x => $record) {
        $item = [// $item is now a sub-array
            'instruction'=>$record->step,
            'id'=>$x
        ];
        $items[] = $item; // Add the sub-array to the main array, creating your second dimension
    } 
}
```